# 行列演算プログラムの結果がソフトウェアと自作IPコアで一致しない

Tags: fpga, zynq, vivado

CQ出版社発行の雑誌「インターフェース」(2019年1月号) を参考に、Ultra96でYOLOv3の高速化をしようと考えています。

現在、高速化用の行列乗算ロジック回路を組み込み、本に乗っていたプログラムをgccでコンパイルして実行ファイルmatrixを作りました。実行すると以下のようになりました。

```
root@xilinx-ultra96-reva-2018_2:/uio_irq_sample# ./matrix 
NG: hw 0.000000, sw 55551.996094
NG: hw 0.000000, sw 55634.667969
NG: hw 0.000000, sw 55717.335938
               省略
NG: hw 0.000000, sw 2830176.000000
NG: hw 0.000000, sw 2835549.500000
NG: hw 0.000000, sw 2840922.750000
NG: hw 0.000000, sw 2846296.000000
OK: 0, NG: 1024, Total: 1024
```

このように結果が一致しませんでした。
もしやられた方がいらっしゃったらアドバイスをお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

出力が全部０になってるってことはまるっきり間違ってるということになろうかと思いますが。

Comment: gccでのコンパイルを間違っていました。